# DiscordPy Tempmute Command with more than only one duration option

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to code a temp mute command, but I dont get how to make it, that I can give 2 arguments, not just only one like the code below. I want to make a command like this: "!tempmute @user 1d3h10m1s" and not just only "!tempmute @user 1h" or "!tempmute @user 1s".
Please help me I've spent the hole day on this and I don't get it...

```
@bot.command(aliases=['tempmute'])
@commands.has_permission(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time=None, *, reason=None):
if not member:
    await ctx.send("You must mention a member to mute!")
elif not time:
    await ctx.send("You must mention a time!")
else:
    if not reason:
        reason="No reason given"
    #Now timed mute manipulation
    try:
        seconds = time[:-1] #Gets the numbers from the time argument, start to -1
        duration = time[-1] #Gets the timed maniulation, s, m, h, d
        if duration == "s":
            seconds = seconds * 1
        elif duration == "m":
            seconds = seconds * 60
        elif duration == "h":
            seconds = seconds * 60 * 60
        elif duration == "d":
            seconds = seconds * 86400
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid duration input")
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("Invalid time input")
        return
    guild = ctx.guild
    Muted = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not Muted:
        Muted = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    await member.add_roles(Muted, reason=reason)
    muted_embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted a user", description=f"{member.mention} Was muted by {ctx.author.mention} for {reason} to {time}")
    await ctx.send(embed=muted_embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    await member.remove_roles(Muted)
    unmute_embed = discord.Embed(title="Mute over!", description=f'{ctx.author.mention} muted to {member.mention} for {reason} is over after {time}")
    await ctx.send(embed=unmute_embed)
```

Comment: In that case you must split the Time argument using the letters as parameter for .split(). It won't be easy but it's not impossible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your input in the format `1d3h10m1s`, we can use [regex split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to handle the time input.
I haven't checked the rest of your code. But now you have seconds calculated, so give it a go. You're on the right track.

```py
import re
...
@bot.command(aliases=['tempmute'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True) # not .has_permission
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member=None, userInput=None, *, reason="No reason given"):
    inputSplit = re.split('(\d+)', userInput)
#   inputSplit looks like ['', '1', 'd', '3', 'h', '10', 'm', '1', 's']
    del inputSplit[0]
#   inputSplit now looks like ['1', 'd', '3', 'h', '10', 'm', '1', 's']

    seconds = 0

#  Looping through inputSplit, from first to last letter
    for i in range(1, len(inputSplit),2):
        timeModifier = inputSplit[i]     # Modifier is the letter
        timeValue = int(inputSplit[i-1]) # Value is number before modifier

        # Same if loop as yours. Checking modifiers and adding the value
        if timeModifier == "d":
            seconds += 86400 * timeValue
        elif timeModifier == "h":
            seconds += 3600 * timeValue
        elif timeModifier == "m":
            seconds += 60 * timeValue
        elif timeModifier == "s":
            seconds += timeValue
# just for checking
    print(f"Timeout time in seconds: {seconds}. Reason: {reason}")
...
```

From my test:

```
input:
>> mute @member 1d3h10m1s You know what you did

output:
>> Timeout time in seconds: 97801. Reason: You know what you did
```